# How can I find asymptote of this function?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have been trying this the whole night and couldn't find the answer. This is homework, by the way.
$$f(x) = \sqrt{x^2+1}$$

Comment: What exactly did you try? What kind of techniques do you know?

Comment: By using Hopital rule, ended always up with infinity..

Comment: What rules do you know other than L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246386/finding-asymptotes-of-exponential-function-and-one-sided-limit).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $g(x) = x$, because $f(x) - g(x)$ goes to zero as $x$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Since $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, the best we can hope for is an oblique asymptote. Noting that $x^2 + 1 \approx x^2$ for very large $x$, we could guess that $f(x) - x \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

To prove this a bit more formally, consider the quantity

$$\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - x = \left(\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - x\right) \frac{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + x}$$ and see if you can simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

To find an asymptote of a function $y = f(x)$, one needs to evaluate a limits
$$
k = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac yx \\
b = \lim_{x \to \infty} (y - kx)
$$
In general, you need to evaluate two pairs of limits when $x \to \pm \infty$, since they might not coincide, which is the case in your problem:
\begin{align}
k_1 &= \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac yx = \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac {\sqrt{x^2+1}}x = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \sqrt{1+\frac 1{x^2}} = 1 \\
k_2 &= \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac yx = \lim_{x \to -\infty}\frac {\sqrt{x^2+1}}x = \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac {\sqrt{x^2+1}}{-x} = -\lim_{x \to +\infty} \sqrt{1+\frac 1{x^2}} = -1 \\
b_1 &= \lim_{x \to +\infty} (y - k_1x) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \sqrt{x^2-1} - x = \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac {\left ( \sqrt{x^2-1} - x \right )\left( \sqrt{x^2-1} + x\right )}{\sqrt{x^2-1}+x} = \\
&= -\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac 1{\sqrt{x^2-1}+x} = 0 \\
b_2 &= \left | \text{same analysis} \right | = 0
\end{align}
So, your function has two oblique asymptotes when $x \to -\infty$ and $x \to +\infty$ correspondingly:
$$
y = \pm x
$$

[image: asym]

Answer (score 0):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246386/finding-asymptotes-of-exponential-function-and-one-sided-limit). Here is how you advance

> $$ f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}=\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}=|x|\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}\sim_{x\to \pm \infty} |x|. $$

**Note:**

> $$ \sqrt{x^2}=|x|. $$

Comment: Mhenni, this method is very dangerous, if not incorrect. Try it out with SQRT[x²+x] According to your method, the slant asymptote will still be the y = x (or -x) but now it is incorrect. The limit law does not apply if one limit (here |x|) does not exist for x→ infinity. In my example, the slant asymtote for x→inf would be y = x + 0.5