# Find an accurate value of $f(x)=\sqrt{4x^2+x}-2x$ for large values of x. Calculate $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

My works:

$x^2$ can be very large if x is large, thus the function has lose-of-significance error and we need to reformulate it. $$ f(x)=\sqrt{4x^2+x}-2x=\sqrt{x(4x+1)}-2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{4x+1}-2\sqrt{x})$$ The latter will not have any lose-of-significance error in the evaluation.

**I am not sure if I did this correctly and I do not know how to compute the limit...**

Comment: I really want to find the accurate value of this function, please don't edit it any more.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246386/finding-asymptotes-of-exponential-function-and-one-sided-limit).

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Completely unrelated, actually. That you posted an answer over there should not be enough to point to it.

Answer (score 5):

I would factor out the $2x$ from both terms, and at a crucial point use the Binomial expansion for $(1+a)^{1/2}$:
\begin{align}
\sqrt{4x^2+x}-2x&=2x\left[\frac{\sqrt{4x^2+x}}{\sqrt{4x^2}}-1\right]\\
&=2x\left[\sqrt{1+\frac1{4x}}-1\right]\\
&=2x\left[-1+1+\frac12\cdot\frac1{4x}-\frac18\left(\frac{1}{4x}\right)^2+\cdots\right]\\
&=2x\left[ \frac1{8x}-\frac1{128x^2}+\cdots \right]\\
&=1/4-\text{(small)}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. Can you please tell me whether the accurate value of this function is correct or not?

Comment: What is the meaning of the expression “accurate value”? Or, what form of description of this accurate value are you looking for?

Comment: Formula that does not involve lose-of-significance error in the evaluation. There is a problem that is similar to this one:[Question 8](http://www.mehrpouyan.info/numerical_analysis/HWs/Homework2-sol.pdf)

Comment: In view of the form of the acceptable answer to Question 8, I think that saying the limit is $1/4$ would suffice.

Answer (score 4):

Setting $\frac1x=h,$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty^+}\sqrt{4x^2+x}-2x=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{4+h}-2}h\ \ \ \ (1)$$

**Method** $1:$

Now, $$\frac{\sqrt{4+h}-2}h=\frac{(4+h)-2^2}{h(\sqrt{4+h}+2)}=\frac1{\sqrt{4+h}+2}\text{ if }h\ne0$$

Here  as $h\to0,h\ne0$

Can you take it from here?

**Method** $2:$

This has strong resemblance with your method

$\displaystyle \sqrt{4+h}=2\left(1+\frac h4\right)^{\frac12}=2\left(1+\frac12\cdot\frac h4+O(h^2)\right)$ (Using [Maclaurin series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) )

$\displaystyle\implies \sqrt{4+h}-2=\frac h4+O(h^2) $

Now, I leave the rest for you to complete

**Method** $3:$

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{4+h}-2}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sqrt{4+h}-\sqrt4}h=\frac{d(\sqrt x)}{dx}_{(\text{ at } x=4)}=\frac1{2\sqrt x}_{(\text{ at } x=4)}$$

**Method** $4:$

Apply [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) on $(1)$

Comment: @walterudoing, how about this?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I think it's correct. What about the accurate value? I'm really concerned about that. An example can be seen in [Question 8](http://www.mehrpouyan.info/numerical_analysis/HWs/Homework2-sol.pdf).

Comment: @walterudoing, can't derive that from all my hints?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\sqrt{4x^2+x}-2x = \dfrac{\sqrt{4x^2+x}+2x}{\sqrt{4x^2+x}+2x} \cdot \sqrt{4x^2+x}-2x = \dfrac{4x^2+x-4x^2}{\sqrt{4x^2+x}+2x} = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4x^2+x}+2x}$$
Hence, use $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{4x^2+x}+2x}$ for computation purposes, especially when $x$ is large. There is no catastrophic cancellation of digits as opposed to evaluating $\sqrt{4x^2+x}-2x$ directly.

Comment: That can be estimated even closer - $\sqrt{4x^2+x}\approx 2x+\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: I think that this post addresses the problem of loss of significance error when "x" takes very large errors. If using a computer, where using a bunch a terms from series expansions could not be effcetive, I think that the best solution is what user17762 proposes.

Comment: Downvoters why don't you pinpoint the mistake when its not obvious